# Getting message from google play "your device isn't compatible with this version" in most of devices except nexus 5

Tags: android, permissions

Am using below listed uses permission and try to google everything related to these but still not found exect issue and unable to solve please suggest any solution or point me where am doing worng?

```html
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

App sdk versions are as following

> minSdkVersion 16
>           targetSdkVersion 23

Comment: I ran into the same problem, is there something new regarding this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: @ReuvenChacha after searching i was found that there are some other permission which are included in to project from external libs so I just override permission and set   tools:node="remove"   for non required uses-permission